# Bypass SSL validation with fsockopen

Tags: php, ssl, fsockopen

I am trying to set up a connection with the PHP fsockopen function.
I am using SSL (self-signed) and don't want the fsockopen function to validate the SSL certificate.

Function call:

```
fsockopen('ssl://someurl.com', 1234, $iErrno, $sErrStr, 10);
```

Is it a possibility to bypass the validation by setting some options?

I know that this can be done with cURL, but the class I am using is built around the fsockopen function, so I want to at least check if the above is possible to prevent any unnecessary work :)